# How to change windows without going full circle?

Tags: 12.04, application-switcher

I'm used to [alt]+[tab] to change windows and I've installed Compiz Config Settings Manager (CCSM) to tweak the default behaviour to my likings.

I've noticed that, after pressing [alt]+[tab], you can only go forward (press [tab] again). You cannot go backward (pressing [shift]+[tab], maintaining [alt]). This means that, when you pass the window you want to use, you have to go full circle.

Is there a way to tweak the switcher to do that? I believe that this was how it used to work in 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here's what to do, install CCSM:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

And under Window Management, mark the option 'Static Application Switcher'.

Now you can go forward [alt]+[tab] or backward [alt]+[shift]+[tab] in your open applications.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify CCSM is already installed. I have the static application switcher enabled...

Comment: Well it works like this here, but i'm using gnome-session-fallback and not Unity...